# HTML elements not rendering on Gatsby website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

**What I am doing:**

Creating my first website in Gatsby.js. Trying to render an HTML element "onClick" of a navigation link. When someone clicks one of the links, I want it to show a dropdown menu.

```
export function DropDownMenu(props) {
        return (
               <p>{props}</p>
        )
}

const Header = () => {

    // const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Nav>
            <StyledLinkBox to="/"><Logo/></StyledLinkBox>
            <Bars />
            <NavMenu>
                {headerMenuData.map((item, index, dropdown) => (
                    <NavLink to={item.link} key={index} onClick={() => {
                        item.dropdown.map((item, index) => (
                            <DropDownMenu props={item} key={index}/>
                        ))}
                    }>
                        {item.title}
                    </NavLink>
                ))}
            <StyledButton>Early Access</StyledButton>
            </NavMenu>
        </Nav>
    )
}
```

**Notes:**

I have tried to use useState to call another function here, but that doesn't seem to work, as then you have to click twice for anything to happen.

If you replace <DropDownMenu...> within the map function with a console.log, it will print out all the elements that need to appear, which is strange.

So if it can do that, and the mapping function is working correctly, why can't I see `<p>{props}</p>` for every item?

Comment: Have you tried ```onclick``` instead of ```onClick```?

Comment: onClick works, it prints out the console.log as I mentioned above. Your suggestion means that it doesn't work at all.

Comment: In the DropDownMenu component you are getting props object and you want show this obj , try {props} in the input of component or use props.props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
export function DropDownMenu({props}) {
        return (
               <p>{props}</p> /* same as props.props */
        )
}

const Header = () => {

    // const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Nav>
            <StyledLinkBox to="/"><Logo/></StyledLinkBox>
            <Bars />
            <NavMenu>
                {headerMenuData.map((item, index, dropdown) => (
                    <NavLink to={item.link} key={index} onClick={() => {
                        item.dropdown.map((item, index) => (
                            <DropDownMenu props={item} key={index}/>
                        ))}
                    }>
                        {item.title}
                    </NavLink>
                ))}
            <StyledButton>Early Access</StyledButton>
            </NavMenu>
        </Nav>
    )
}
```

You are sending `item` as `props` and the component is also, by default, is getting `props` (if you send it), so you need to restructure it or access the data by `props.props`.

You can do:

```
 <DropDownMenu item={item} key={index}/>
```

And:

```
export function DropDownMenu({item}) {
        return (
               <p>{item}</p> /* same as props.item */
        )
}
```

For a more succinct approach.